# Update model - Play 2.4.3

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.4

I have the following code in my update function.

I use the form that I pre-fill with data but when I submit the form i CANNOT update the existing object even if I set client.id manually.

Is it correct to use the commented code in order to first get the object from DB and then update every field one by one?

```
    Form<Client> clientForm = form(Client.class).bindFromRequest();

    Map<String, String> data = clientForm.data();

    if (clientForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(addEditClient.render("Edit Client", "Update Client", clientID, false, clientForm));
    } else {
        // do stuff
        Client client = clientForm.get();

         client.contact = User.findByID("1");

        for(ClientTask ct : client.taskSet) {
            Task t = Task.findByID(ct.t.id);
            ct.t = t;
        }

        client.id = clientID;

        //Client c = Client.findByID(clientID);
        //c.name = "test12";
        //etc...
        //c.save();

        client.save();

        return GO_HOME;
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception?

Comment: Yes because it tries to create another object with the same ID which is unique

Comment: Your example is a little bit difficult to understand. What do you want to achieve? What is the exception?

Comment: I have an existing model. I create a form and fill the form. I show the form to the user to edit the model and then I would like to just get it back from the form and update it into the DB. Just perform a regular update. But when I use save it just creates a new entry in the table instead of updating the existing one.

Comment: you need to add your save method here and make sure that it updates existing object if you are using an ORM.

Comment: Can you show us what the Client class looks like?